# How is a persistent toolbar in android best implemented?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In the Google Music App, when a song is played, a tool bar at the bottom of the screen appears with media information and controls. I want this same functionality.

Currently, I am using a toolbar.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/primaryColor"
 android:id="@+id/tbMedia"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It is displayed when audio is played. However, what I'm doing feels hacky.
Is using a toolbar the best way?

Comment: I dont see any problem in using toolbar like this way. you can use it how you want.It is not for only actionbar

Comment: I see. That makes me feel better. I often get by with tutorials since I am new to programming for android. However, I couldn't find anything specific on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a Toolbar to control your media. That's what action bars are for, and Toolbars are just the newest way of implementing action bars. If you want a bar at the bottom of the screen, consider using a split action bar.

Here's the relevant info from the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) dev guide:

> To enable split action bar when using the support library, you must do two things:
>
> 1. Add uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" to each  element or to the  element. This attribute is understood only by API level 14 and higher (it is ignored by older versions).
> 2. To support older versions, add a  element as a child of each  element that declares the same value for "android.support.UI_OPTIONS".
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <manifest ...>
>     <activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
>         <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
>                    android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
>     </activity>
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: Thank you hungryghost and Shvet.